# Inline Code in DokuWiki

Tags: syntax-highlighting, wiki, markup, inline-code, dokuwiki

I'm looking for a way to include code as part of a paragraph in DokuWiki like I can by adding backtick escapes in StackOverflow `like _so_`. Simply adding `<code>bla</code>` puts code on it's own line.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You probably want to use `''%%here is code%%''`. This formats it in monospace (`''`) and prevents any interpretion of possible wiki markup (`%%`).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because without it characters can get encoded, such as quotes in to smart quotes, which is a nightmare when you want to copy and paste.

Comment: surely a plugin could be written that maps `\`foo\`` to `''%%foo%%''`?

Comment: You can setup your own buttons using the custombuttons plugin: https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:custombuttons

Answer (score 17):

I was able to find an answer to my own question. Add quotes around the in-text code `''like this''`. Simple, short, and works great.

Comment: This answer is _wrong_, because just `''monospace''` quoted text is still interpreted as having DokuWiki formatting, and you could get `--` in your code replaced with `–`. Andreas Gohr answer, above, _is correct_.

Comment: well, really, the question never specified that it needed to be safe, this actually answers the question perfectly. Given that Gohr's answer comes so many hours after and is such a minor change it should have just been a suggestion comment to improve this answer