# Pandoc : convert dokuwiki with inline code to html

Tags: html, pandoc, dokuwiki

I have some documentation formatted in dokuwiki, with this inline code :

`''%%database.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_database_name%%''`

Based on this answer : [Inline Code in DokuWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662856/inline-code-in-dokuwiki) it's the best way to write inline code with dokuwiki. The '%%' part prevents any wiki interpretion of your code.

With dokuwiki preview it is displayed correctly, the '%%' part is not displayed : database.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_database_name

But when I try to convert from dokuwiki to HTML with Pandoc, the '%%' part is still there and I have something like this in my HTML file : %%database.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_database_name%%

Am I missing something with the pandoc command ?

I use this command : `pandoc dokuwiki_file.txt -f dokuwiki -t html5 -s -o html_file.html --metadata pagetitle="page title"`

Thanks !

Comment: I thin pandoc currently just does not handle the `%%`, you could open an issue on github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues with a reference to the dokuwiki documentation for that...

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to preprocess the dokwiki markup using something like sed. Let me know if you need an example.